# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' C#

Tags: c#, .net

Please help build Release error

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Runtime
{
    class Program
    {
        static Timer timer;
        static string date = "";
        static string time = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            date = args[0].ToString();


            time = args[1].ToString();
            schedule_Timer();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void schedule_Timer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("### Timer Started ###");

            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date + " " + time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            //if (nowTime > scheduledTime)
            //{
            //    return;
            //}


            double tickTime = (double)(scheduledTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(tickTime);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();

        }


        static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("### Timer Stopped ### \n");
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("### Scheduled Task Started ### \n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Do - Performing scheduled task\n");
            Console.WriteLine("### Task Finished ### \n\n");
            //----------------------------------------------------------------


            //schedule_Timer();
        }
    }
}
```

show error

> Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in Runtime.exe An
>   unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred
>   in Runtime.exe Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> The program '[7172] Runtime.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Line 25 Error
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  Could not read state file "obj\Release\Runtime.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache". Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Runtime

Comment: So.. since you don't check the args length, you expect that every time the program is launched, the arguments are passed through? are you sure args[0] and args[1] exist? before you call the ToString()
if launching in VS, please make sure both debug and release config have the parameters set..

Answer (score 0):

at first glance I would say,`args[]` doesn't hold any or only 1 element.
you should add a check, before accessing it.

```
if (args == null)
{
    if (args.Length > 0) // or for your specific case: (args.Length >= 2)
        //do your stuff (including further appropriate checks)
}
```

EDIT: changed `//do whatever you like` in order to address rmjoia's comment

Comment: I think "//do whatever you like" is a bit extreme just because length > 0, but as added in the comment, you shouldn't access indexes without make sure that they exist first.. so I would just check all the expected, or eventually map them to a dictionary or some other object that makes more clear sense of what is going on